# WPF - DataGrid does not update when bound data gets updated

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have a WPF application with a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection`.

One of the elements of the `ObservableCollection` (`ViewLock`) is a `Boolean` that binds two-way to a `CheckBox`, and I want things to happen when the application user checks or unchecks the `CheckBox`. For that, I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This part seems to work, as a `MessageBox` opens up everytime I change a `CheckBox` value as set in my `ObservableCollection` definition.

However, I have two other elements of my WPF that bind to the same `Boolean`: One is the color of the `dataRow` set using `RowStyle`, the other is the `IsEnabled` of a `ComboBox`. Neither of those two things get updated when the value of `ViewLock` is updated. They do get updated when I force the `DataGrid` to refresh using a button.

I want my `RowStyle` and `ComboBox IsEnabled` to update automatically and instantly when the value of `ViewLock` gets updated, but so far none of my attempts led anywhere.

What am I missing here?

Here is my **XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_ViewTemplate"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name ="Canvas1" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <Label Content="All Views" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="57"/>
            <DataGrid Name="DataGridGeneral" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="239" Canvas.Left="68" Canvas.Top="61" Width="661">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewLock }" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewLock, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="View Name" Binding="{Binding ViewName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="View Template">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding VTList}" IsEnabled="{Binding ViewLock }" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Lock/Unlock">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ViewLock, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Canvas>
        <Button Content="OK" Click="OK_OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="717,380,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="667,380,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And my **codebehind:**

```
Imports System.Windows.Markup
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Class MainWindow
    ReadOnly ViewClass As New InfoList

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        ViewClass.FillLists()
        DataGridGeneral.ItemsSource = ViewClass.ViewList

    End Sub

    Private Sub OK_OnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        ViewClass.ViewList(1).ViewName = "Updated"
        CType(Canvas1.Children(1), DataGrid).Items.Refresh()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is how I defined my **ObservableCollection** and initiate `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class GeneralObservableCollection

    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Friend Sub New(ViewName As String, VTList As List(Of String), ViewLock As Boolean)

        _ViewName = ViewName
        _VTList = VTList
        _ViewLock = ViewLock

    End Sub

    Private _ViewName As String
    Public Property ViewName() As String
        Get
            Return _ViewName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _ViewName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _VTList As List(Of String)
    Public Property VTList() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _VTList
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
            _VTList = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ViewLock As Boolean
    Public Property ViewLock() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _ViewLock
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _ViewLock = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged(ViewLock)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal ViewLock As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(ViewLock))
        ViewName = "Modified"
        MessageBox.Show("DataGridGeneral" & ViewLock & ViewName)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is how I fill in my ObservableCollection for the datagrid:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Public Class InfoList

    Public ViewList As New ObservableCollection(Of GeneralObservableCollection)

    Public Sub AddView(ViewName As String, VTList As List(Of String), ViewLock As Boolean)
        ViewList.Add(New GeneralObservableCollection(ViewName, VTList, ViewLock))
    End Sub

    Public Sub FillLists()

        Dim VTList As New List(Of String)({"None", "1/2"" conc", "3/4"" steel", "Plan View"})

        Me.ViewList.Clear()
        Me.AddView("Level 1", VTList, False)
        Me.AddView("Level 1A", VTList, False)
        Me.AddView("S200/AS", VTList, False)
        Me.AddView("S201/01", VTList, False)
        Me.AddView("S201/02", VTList, False)
        Me.AddView("S201/03", VTList, True)

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub UpdateGridView(GridName As String)
        MessageBox.Show(GridName)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: I'm not certain about vb.net syntax, but it seems to me you have the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008043/1506454. I'm suspect this line: `NotifyPropertyChanged(ViewLock)`. in c# it should have been `NotifyPropertyChanged("ViewLock")`

Comment: I also suggest to chnage parameter name in NotifyPropertyChanged method to avoid collisions: `Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal PropertyName As String) RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName ))`

Comment: @ASh You were right, my `NotifyPropertyChanged` implementation was wrong! If you want to turn your comments into an answer, I will accept it. Otherwise I will mark my question as duplicate. Thanks!